# Network simulator - reading packets from file

Tags: networking, simulator, ns2, ns-3

I would like to ask if it is possible add some packet file like .pcap or .txt (packet statistic) to ns input. For example, if I want insert some packets to device interface.
Is it possible with ns2 / ns3?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible with ns2.. not sure about ns3.. in order to do it in ns2, you need to enable 'emulation' in ns2.
to emulate ns2 --
1. in terminal.. switch to root mode
2. move to directory 'ns-2.35' in your ns2 installation.
3. run 'make nse'
4. run './configure'
and Emulation is activated in ns2.
now in you tcl file 
1. create a Tap Agent like '**set tap1 [new Agent/Tap]**'.
2. crate a Network Object like ' **set nob [new Network/Pcap/File]**;
3. provide the path to Pcap file like' $nob open readonly **Real/xplico_youtube_mail.pcap**'
the file is located in ns-2.35 folder in given path.
4. in Tap Agent, provide network agent as network.. **$tap1 network $nob
$ns attach-agent $node_(0) $tap1;**
5. connect the Tap to other node.. and its done.